# How do I reference my stylesheet of Bootstrap using CodeIgniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm loading a view by doing `$this->load->view('index')`.

My directory looks like this

- application
- assets/css/bootstrap.css

Inside the view (in `applications/views/index.php`) I'm referencing inside the head tags like this:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the controller only loads the elements of html without any styles of Bootstrap css. Am I referencing the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the url helper, `site_url()` function makes it easy:

```
<link href="<?php echo site_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" >
```

You can also use the HTML helper and the `link_tag()` function:

```
echo link_tag('assets/css/bootstrap.css');
```

To use the helpers, add these lines in your controller constructor:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('html');
```

Alternatively, you can globally load these helpers in your `application/config/autoload.php` file.  See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html  for more information.

Comment: The problem was solved using <?php base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter provides its own way of adding .css file into the view. You only have to update the "config.php" file in the application folder with $config['css'] = '/assets/css/bootstrap.css'; Then declare a data array in your model class which load the config and  use it in the style file. Go to following link. The process is discussed with an example. Ignore their directory url as it is done with earlier version of CI.

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Form-Creating-Beautiful-Form-Code-P243.html