# Reference twitter-bootstrap inside a Codeigniter view

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to reference the `css` files of bootstrap inside my views. I'm using `Codeigniter` as my framework. CI has a folder for the views, but I haven't been able to reference the stylesheets. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>
            Login
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
```

And so on... But the style is just plain html.

I know there are plenty of questions in stackoverflow regarding this, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463253/how-do-i-reference-my-stylesheet-of-bootstrap-using-codeigniter?rq=1), but I haven't found a solution in them. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

It was a mix of not putting the correct `DOCTYPE` and also for some reason I had to use `<?php base_url();?>` for the urls... If someone could explain this to me it would be great to learn more.